# Insert xmltype into xmltype in specified place [PL/SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have problem with insert xmltype into another xmltype in specified place in pl/sql.

First variable v_xml has the form:

```
<ord>
  <head>
    <ord_code>123</ord_code>
    <ord_date>01-01-2015</ord_date>
  </head>
</ord>
```

And the second v_xml2:

```
<pos>
  <pos_code>456</pos_code>
  <pos_desc>description</pos_desc>
</pos>
```

My purpose is get something like this:

```
<ord>
  <head>
    <ord_code>123</ord_code>
    <ord_date>01-01-2015</ord_date>
  </head>
  <!-- put the second variable in this place - after closing <head> tag -->
  <pos>
    <pos_code>456</pos_code>
    <pos_desc>description</pos_desc>
  </pos>
</ord>
```

What shoud I do with my code?

```
declare
  v_xml  xmltype;
  v_xml2 xmltype;
begin
  -- some code
  -- some code
  -- v_xml and v_xml2 has the form as I define above
end;
```

Is anyone able to help me with this problem? As I know there are functions like insertchildxml, appendchildxml or something like this...
I found few solution in pure SQL, but I don't know how to move this in PL/SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mentioned [appendChildXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm#CHDFGJHH), like here:

```
declare
  v_xml  xmltype := xmltype('<ord>
                               <head>
                                 <ord_code>123</ord_code>
                                 <ord_date>01-01-2015</ord_date>
                               </head>
                             </ord>');
  v_xml2 xmltype:= xmltype('<pos>
                              <pos_code>456</pos_code>
                              <pos_desc>description</pos_desc>
                            </pos>');
  v_output xmltype;
begin
  select appendChildXML(v_xml, 'ord', v_xml2) 
    into v_output from dual;

  -- output result
  dbms_output.put_line( substr( v_output.getclobval(), 1, 1000 ) );
end;
```

Output:

```
<ord>
  <head>
    <ord_code>123</ord_code>
    <ord_date>01-01-2015</ord_date>
  </head>
  <pos>
    <pos_code>456</pos_code>
    <pos_desc>description</pos_desc>
  </pos>
</ord>
```

Answer (score 2):

[appendChildXML](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions012.htm#SQLRF06201) is deprecated at 12.1

So here is a solution using [XMLQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions264.htm#SQLRF06209)

```
DECLARE

   l_head_xml   XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<ord>
                                                 <head>
                                                    <ord_code>123</ord_code>
                                                    <ord_date>01-01-2015</ord_date>
                                                 </head>
                                              </ord>');

   l_pos_xml   XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<pos>
                                                <pos_code>456</pos_code>
                                                <pos_desc>description</pos_desc>
                                             </pos>');

   l_complete_xml  XMLTYPE;

BEGIN

   SELECT XMLQUERY('for $i in $h/ord/head
                    return <ord>
                           {$i}
                           {for $j in $p/pos
                           return $j}                                 
                           </ord>'                                                                        
                   PASSING l_head_xml AS "h", 
                           l_pos_xml AS "p"
                   RETURNING CONTENT)
     INTO l_complete_xml
     FROM dual;

   dbms_output.put_line(l_complete_xml.getstringval());

END;
```

Comment: Ian - If <ord> has attributes, can you please explain how you also return them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using XMLQuery

```
DECLARE
l_src XMLTYPE:=XMLTYPE('<ord>
  <head>
    <ord_code>123</ord_code>
    <ord_date>01-01-2015</ord_date>
  </head>
</ord>');

l_dst XMLTYPE:=XMLTYPE('<pos>
  <pos_code>456</pos_code>
  <pos_desc>description</pos_desc>
</pos>');
l_final CLOB;

BEGIN

SELECT XMLQUERY('copy $tmp := $p1 modify
                insert node $p2 as last into $tmp
                return $tmp' PASSING l_src as "p1",l_dst as "p2" RETURNING CONTENT).getClobval() into l_final from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_final);
END;
```